# Practical uses of $p$ norms for $p\notin \{1,2,\infty\}$?

Tags: soft-question, normed-spaces

We all love normed spaces, but it seems like the $1$-, $2$-, and $\infty$-norms get the lion's share of the love. That's not admittedly not without good reason, but what of the other unsung norms with $1 < p < \infty$? $3$ and $4$ seem like nice numbers. Does anyone use their norms? Maybe $3/2$ for when you can't decide between the $1$- and $2$-norms? Or perhaps something spicier--using the $\pi$-norm would certainly turn a few heads.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality  might be one of them

Answer (score 1):

To solve sparse recovery problems involving the $\ell_0$ "norm" $\|\cdot\|_0$, sometimes folks solve a sequence of smooth optimization problems with the $\ell_0$ term replaced by $\|\cdot\|_{p_n}$, and $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of positive numbers converging monotonically zero. This apparently gives you a pretty reasonable trajectory towards a solution of the original nonsmooth problem.